# RPC Executor Service Error when automating google sign in option (Cypress)

Tags: google-chrome, googlesigninaccount, cypress-origin

I have a webpage being tested using Cypress Automation. Within this webpage, it has the option to sign in via Google.

I was able to create a script for this but it is giving me an error coming from Google itself.

[image]

Note that this is occurring for Edge and Chrome. It is working fine for Firefox.

Is anyone familiar with this error and how to resolve this?

I am running Cypress v12.12

Node v16.14.0

Windows 10

Latest Chrome v113

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this myself by removing my ad blocker plugins (uBlock and Ghostery) and then logging in.

I have since added those ad blockers back in and it seems to be working fine.

Sorry I can't tell you in more detail as to why this happened, but that is a potential fix!